# Importing PFX without Password throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I want to import a `PFX certificate` using `certutil.exe`. When i use this process:

```
Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -p {0} -importPFX \"{1}\"", passwordPFX, _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();
```

It works fine everything. (In this case the certificate is created using a password).  But if i create a certificate without password and try to import like this:

```
Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -p -importPFX \"{0}\"", _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();
```

Then i get an error saying that: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminted.`
What could i be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your  `Arguments = string.Format("-f -p -importPFX \"{0}\"", _pathServerCerPFX)` line of code you are using `-p` which basically stands for the `password` parameter.  Removing that part of code could solve your issue.Your code should look like below:

```
Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -importPFX \"{0}\"", _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Although escaping -p, I still get the prompt waiting for me to input a password. How do you bypass this prompt in your code?

Comment: In batch I was able to use `-p ""`

Comment: In my case, `-p ""` is still not working. I have to use `echo "" | certutil ...` to trick silly microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try: (Note the `-p ""`)

```
Process.Start(
                new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = "certutil",
                    Arguments = string.Format("-f -p "" -importPFX \"{0}\"", _pathServerCerPFX)
                }
            ).WaitForExit();
```